# Frequent updates to Angular controller not reflected in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, signalr

Working on an interesting issue with Angular and frequent updates from SignalR.

on the server, I have a singleton instance of a manager which is currently set to send updates every 500ms

```
    public void StartTest() {
        var i = 0;
        while (i < 1000) {
            if (_cancelRequested) {
                _cancelRequested = false;
                return;
            }
            _context.Clients.All.sent(i++);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
```

in my view i'm using "controller as vm" syntax:

```
{{vm.status}}
```

finally in my controller (on signalR initialization):

```
    // Using 'Controller As' syntax, so we assign this to the vm variable (for viewmodel).
    var vm = this;
    vm.status = '';
    ...
    function activateSignal() {
        var hub = $.connection.mailerHub;

        hub.client.sent = function (counter) {
            log(' singal_R ## event: sent ' + counter);  // <-- this works on every update
            vm.status = counter;  // this works only on last update, or if stop is pressed it writes the most recent update. 
        };
```

that code does 2 things: writes to log (this sends a toastr update to the browser), and sets the status variable on the controller.

the log comments are reflected in the browser as expected, every half second i get the nice toastr notification with event number, however setting the variable doesn't have any effect, until i request stop, or it reaches 999.

when i press stop, vm.status gets written out with last sequence number, or when the entire thing stops, it writes out 999.

so it appears to be some issue with frequency of setting properties on vm? would i need something like $scope.$watch to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it is not clear enough for me exactly what you are trying to achieve, but it looks like you are updating your model outside the control of angular. So, you need to notify angular of what you are doing.

Most likely, something like this should solve the problem:

```
hub.client.sent = function (counter) {
   $scope.apply(function(){
      log(' singal_R ## event: sent ' + counter);
      vm.status = counter;
   });
};
```

Comment: i am not using scope .. using the "controller as" notation, so all my properties are set on controller. it seems to work for everything accept for when updates are happening in a row like that..yet the last update comes through..

Comment: @SonicSoul I have to agree with Edwin's answer. You are in fact still using scope, albeit in the background. The "controller as" notation simply means that Angular is publishing the controller instance onto scope and that is why your properties are accessible in the view. E.g. if you use `yourController as vm` in the view, there will actually be a property on the scope `$scope.vm`. Since SignalR communicated to the client outside the Angular context, you'll have to use `$scope.$apply` to let Angular know your model has changed.

Comment: So even though you are using `controller as` notation, in some instances like your example or if you want to subscribe to or emit/broadcast events on $scope you'll still need to inject $scope into your controller. This is also one of the reasons I moved away from controller as notations. Nowadays I use `$scope.vm = {};` inside my controller, and then put everything I want to expose to the view on `$scope.vm`.

Comment: oops, my previous comment was too haste. wrapping in $scope.$apply did indeed fix the issue. thanks!